# prestashop 1.5 smarty missing default variables for backend

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I am developing a module **Abc** for PrestaShop 1.5
This is my dir

```
23/10/2012  18:23             1.307 index.php
07/12/2012  18:27    <DIR>          tpl
               -> tpl dir:
               07/12/2012  18:27    <DIR>          .
               07/12/2012  18:27    <DIR>          ..
               07/12/2012  18:39               543 form.tpl
07/12/2012  18:36             4.507 abc.php
```

this is the code i use:

```
class Abc extends Module
{
    public function getContent()
    {
             return $this->display(dirname(__FILE__), 'tpl/form.tpl');
        }
...
}
```

however when i use smarty `{debug}` to print all variables

i don't get the variables `{img_dir}` or `{shop_name}` like i should according to [The official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-UsingSmarty).

I am confused of where to place the template, where the theme, and so on. I only need backoffice(backend) pages. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty variables have global scope. It means that they can be assigned in one file and you will be able to use anywhere and during all life cycle of your script. This way, when you fire hook or use your own tpl on frontend, no matter which controller you use, most likely (although there can be exception for overriding controller) method `FrontController::init()` will be excecuted. In this method most of these global smarty variables are assigned(http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-UsingSmarty):

```
$assign_array = array(
    'img_ps_dir' => _PS_IMG_,
    'img_cat_dir' => _THEME_CAT_DIR_,
    'img_lang_dir' => _THEME_LANG_DIR_,
    'img_prod_dir' => _THEME_PROD_DIR_,
    'img_manu_dir' => _THEME_MANU_DIR_,
    'img_sup_dir' => _THEME_SUP_DIR_,
    'img_ship_dir' => _THEME_SHIP_DIR_,
    'img_store_dir' => _THEME_STORE_DIR_,
    'img_col_dir' => _THEME_COL_DIR_,
    'img_dir' => _THEME_IMG_DIR_,
    'css_dir' => _THEME_CSS_DIR_,
    'js_dir' => _THEME_JS_DIR_,
    'pic_dir' => _THEME_PROD_PIC_DIR_
);
```

Using hook in admin panel, `FrontController::init()` are not excecuted, and that's way you need to assign all these variables in order to use them inside your files.

But anywhere in admin panel you can use module_dir and module_template_dir which are assigned in method `Module::display()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to put extension configuration forms/html inside Modules tab in Prestashop it's better/necessary to do without smarty and it's usually done by some method like displayForm with javascript, html etc. and public method getContent() where you call this function and return html that is necessary to display there. [Here is a old manual for simple extension for 1.4](http://www.ecartservice.net/24072009/writing-your-own-prestashop-module-part-4/) but you can get an idea from it.

From 1.5 it's also possible to set up forms with default fields like it's done in editorial module in [private function initForm()](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/master/modules/editorial/editorial.php)

To have an ability to make something more difficult inside admin panel (with templates) I think that you need to [create your own tab](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Creatingthemodule%27sback-officetab,anditsclass) inside one of the existing or [create your own](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/157626-how-does-admin-tabs-mvc-work/)

In all default modules as I know, tpl css js files (mymodule.tpl) are used to display content on frontend and should be placed in (this is true for 1.5 version, in 1.4 these files were placed in modules root folder and it's still true for a lot of core modules)

- /modules/my_module/views/templates/{front||hook||admin}/my_module.tpl
- /modules/my_module/views/templates/{front||hook||admin}/my_module.css
- /modules/my_module/views/templates/{front||hook||admin}/my_module.js

  Themes' frontend features(but assume it can be true for admin also) should be override like in [prestashop guide Overriding a module's behavior](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingamodule%27sbehavior)